# How to set background color of label in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, jss

Could you please tell me how to set the background color of the `label` in 
react?
I am using `react. + material ui` from [here](https://material-ui.com/).

[Here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/) is there is the concept of writing CSS in `js` when you scroll pages there are few plugins available examples `jss-nested` is using that I try to make `label` color to red or background color to red but I am not able to do that.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxx08jo487) is my code.

I do the following steps:

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";
import jssNested from "jss-nested";
import { create } from "jss";
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styleNode = document.createComment("jss-insertion-point");
document.head.insertBefore(styleNode, document.head.firstChild);

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
const jss = create({
  ...jssPreset(),
  plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, jssNested()],
  // We define a custom insertion point that JSS will look for injecting the styles in the DOM.
  insertionPoint: "jss-insertion-point"
});
```

**on test.js**
to make the background red I used this code

```
const styles = {
  formControl: {
    width: "100%", 
    '& .label': {
      background: 'red'
    },
    // Use multiple container refs in one selector
    '&.selected, &.active': {
      border: '1px solid red'
    }
  },
```

but this code is not working. Check my screen shot I want to make that `label` background to red 
[image]

[image]

don't want to show primary theme to input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.label` to match element with class (or className in React) label and for elements `<label>` use `label` without dot

Comment: thanks your solution is working..one more thing see my update question why this blue line come when I click on input field ,I don't want to  blue border when I click on input field

Comment: I know this primary theme . I don't want this in form controls